# How can I filter the number of products shown in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I filter the number of products shown (50, 100, 150)? I have created an e-commerce website which filters low to high but I can't display products shown. You can refer to attached image. Provide any reference link in react.

[image]

Here's the code:

```js
sortbyshow = (e, { value }) => {
  var prod = this.state.products;
  console.log(prod.length)
  console.log(value)
  var myOrderedShow;
  if (prod > value) {
    myOrderedShow = _.sortBy(prod, ["type", "mrpprice"]).reverse();
  }
  else if (prod > value) {
    myOrderedShow = _.sortBy(prod, ["type", "mrpprice"]).reverse();
  } else myOrderedShow = _.sortBy(prod, (o) => o.mrpprice);

  this.setState({ products: myOrderedShow });
};

<Dropdown
  options={this.state.ss}
  defaultValue={this.state.selected}
  onChange={this.sortbyshow}
/>
```

Comment: Could you please help me anyone.

Comment: The problem is with wrong production in state, not updating or receiving the old one?

Answer (score 1):

In your `render()` function, truncate the array to the correct length

```
render() {
  // `this.state.numberOfProductsPerPage` should contain 
  // the value in the "show" drop down, which is the number 
  // of items per page.

  // `this.state.currentPage` should contain the index
  // of the current page. 
  // e.g. if we on page 2 showing products 51-100 or
  // on page 1 showing products 1-50, 
  // `this.state.currentPage` should contain 1 or 0 respectively
  
  const { 
    currentPage, 
    numberOfProductsPerPage,
    products,
  } = this.state;
  const startIndex = currentPage * numberOfProductsPerPage;

  const pageOfProducts = products.slice(startIndex, startIndex + numberOfProductsPerPage);

  return (
    <Products>
      {pageOfProducts.forEach( (product, i) => 
        <Product key=i />
      )}
    </Products>
  );
}
```

To get the value of the inputs/forms in React, use [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) or [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) forms. Since this is a dropdown, it may be easier to use a library such as [React-Select](https://react-select.com/home).

e.g.

```
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you please use dropdown this point  `this.state.numberOfProductsPerPage` should contain I can't get dropdown value of 50,100

Comment: @SimpleDesign can you explain what you mean? ` this.state.numberOfProductsPerPage` should contain the value of the dropdown, so `50` or `100` or `150` etc. I'll add a link about how you can get that

Comment: @SimpleDesign added it